# Adding XML to Docx

Tags: c#, xml, docx

I am trying to auto generate a docx document using C# with test cases from Microsoft Test Manager. The data that is being inserted has its formatting in XML format e.g.

```
<DIV><P><SPAN xml:lang="en-gb">In the Name field enter "</SPAN><SPAN xml:lang="en-gb" STYLE="font-weight:bold;">Test Clinic</SPAN><SPAN xml:lang="en-gb">" and click Save</SPAN></P></DIV>
```

Is there any way of getting this to be properly formatted automatically or do I have to write my own parser?

Comment: You have to either use `interop` to generate your doc or some third party tool that does it.

Comment: this seems to be HTML. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Do you want to automatically convert this HTML to a docx ? In this case I would rather use pandoc

Comment: Can you help me by telling what you are trying to achieve? Is it Office XML or HTML (then just open the HTML as a file)?